# Ext Grid positioning in Viewport or something

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

Please suggest how can I position my grids on a single page. I am trying to place 3 Grid Panels in two rows with decent space between each grid.Panel. I have three CRUD Grids populated with data from DB ( and it's store ):

var UserGrid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', { ... });

var RoleGrid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', { ... });

var Map = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', { ... });

Now I want to place them in different positions like I mentioned earlier. So, I want to be able to refer to my existing Grids in the Viewport or something.

That is one part of my question. Also, I am really so annoyed by the ExtJS documentation on Sencha. I know many people say it is elaborate. I am very confused what configs or properties or methods I use in each Ext JS object. The documentation does detail them, but I am not able to get hold of when to use what. When do we use options given in 'config'? When do we use options given in 'properties'. When do we use options given in 'events'? More importantly how do we use them !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look how layout system works in ExtJs: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/guide/layouts_and_containers

For your particular case I think you would need to configure viewport with `border` layout, put your first grid into `center` region, and create a container for other two grids in the `south` region.

Also I'd recommend to specify what version of ExtJs you're using.

**UPDATE:**

So normally you would have somewhere in your viewport definition:

```
layout: 'border'
items: [{
   xtype: 'panel', // This your UserGrid
   region: 'center',
   ... 
}, {
   xtype: 'container',
   region: 'south',
   layout: 'vbox',
   items: [{
      xtype: 'panel', // This your RoleGrid
      flex: 1
      ...
   }, {
      xtype: 'panel', // This your Map
      flex: 1
      ...
   }]
   ... 
}]
```

This will be true if you don't have special variables for grid (i.e. if you will not create them manually but let ExtJs create them for you.

Now, if you have any special logic or configuration inside these grids, then you might define your own classes and inherit them from standard panel/grid. In this case you obviously change `xtype: 'panel'` in the code above with proper `xtype` for your class.

If you want to create grids beforehand (there are might be some reason for that, but I rarely do so) you would need to pass `region` configuration to your first grid when creating it:

```
var UserGrid =  Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
   region: 'center',
   ... 
});
```

And then change the viewport code to something like this:

```
layout: 'border'
items: [userGrid, {
   xtype: 'container',
   region: 'south',
   layout: 'vbox',
   items: [RoleGrid, Map]
   ... 
}]
```

Comment: Sha, I have been through them sometime back. The docs say

    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            title: 'Child Panel 1',
        },
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            title: 'Child Panel 2',
        }
    ]

Though it might sound too trivial, that is what I am looking for. eg: But I don't want to add new panels. I want to refer to something which I already created, into my viewport/container. So, just like xtype, title, is there any other config that I can use in 'items' to refer to exisiting components on page. Can u help with some code?

Comment: Posted some code samples. You still haven't specified what version of ExtJs you're using

Comment: Oops my bad. ExtJS 4.2. And that was a very good reference Sha that you provided. I will let you know by today with results of my trials. Thanks once again.

Comment: thank you Sha. It has surely helped me understand the layouts stuff.

Answer (score 1):

As already said, you have to learn to uses the different layouts. See this [demo](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/example/layout-browser/layout-browser.html) to get an idea of what's available.

Now, regarding the structure of the doc, 'configs', 'methods', 'properties', and 'events' are really three different concepts, but only config is specific to Ext. The others are general object oriented concepts.

In a nutshell:

- Properties are the variables that are bound to on object. In the context of Ext, they are almost always read-only. That don't means that you can't change their value (impossible to prevent in Javascript), but that  **you shouldn't**. So you use poperties to read information from existing objects. For example:

  ```
  if (checkbox.checked) { ... }
  ```
- Config options are the option that you can use when you create an object. Almost all constructors in Ext accept one single argument, an object called the config object. So you use config options when you create an object:

  ```
  Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
      width: 200,
      height: 200,
      ...
  });
  ```
- Methods is the name given to functions that belongs to an object. Unlike properties, when you use a method, code is running, so that's what you use for doing things.

  ```
  window.show();
  // using the animate parameter
  window.show(true);
  ```
- Events are things that happen in the application. You can react to them by [attaching listeners](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.util.Observable-method-addListener) (also named callback functions) to them. The parameters that are given for events in the doc are the one that will be passed your callback method.

  ```
  // E.g. displaying an alert when a button is clicked
  button.addListener(
      // name of the event
      'click',
      // the callback function
      function() {
          alert('Clicked!');
      }
  )
  ```

Comment: rixo, thanks a ton for introducing me to the background of these things. I will try to explore more basing on this. Thank you once again.